# Show that f is strictly increasing on specific interval with an alternating n in interval

Tags: calculus

We have that

$f(x) = 2 - x +2x^2 cos( \frac{1}{x} ) $ when x not equal to 0

$f(x) = 2$ when x = 0

$f'(x) = -1 + 4xcos(\frac {1}{x}) + 2sin(\frac{1}{x})$

Show that f(x) is stricly increasing on intervals in the form $[\frac{2}{(4n+1)\pi}, \frac{6}{(12n+1)\pi}]$ for all integers $n\geq1$

I've tried using the mean-value theorem, but I was not able to find an answer. I still think the answer lies in the MVT. Maybe this is solveable with the use of induction?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Certainly not by induction, since this is equivalent to $g:t\mapsto 4\cos t+t(2\sin t-1)$ being $>0$ on each interval $2\pi n+[\pi/6,\pi/2]$ and for this, it is sufficent that $g>0$ on  $[\pi/6,\pi/2]$.

Comment: Show successively that on this interval, $g''<0$, $g'<0$, $g>0$.